# Placement of indices using \bigcirc in math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Consider a definition of iterative function composition in a mathematical document:

```
\begin{align*}
    \bigcirc_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A \\
    \bigcirc_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= f_l \circ (\bigcirc_{i = l + 1}^{u}\ f_i)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

What i don't like is the placement of *i = l* and *u*, because it should be directly below and above the big circle in displaymath.
Now look at this example:

```
\begin{align*}
    \bigodot_{i = l}^{u} f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A \\
    \bigodot_{i = l}^{u} f_i &= f_l \circ (\bigodot_{i = l + 1}^{u} f_i)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

That way the placement is as I wish, but now the big cirle has a little spot within in.
I would like to achieve the placement of the second example, but with the symbol of the first example. Is there a way to do that?

By the way, here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \bigcirc_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A  &&  \text{if $l > u$}\\
        \bigcirc_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= f_l \circ (\bigcirc_{i = l + 1}^{u}\ f_i)  &&  \text{otherwise}
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
        \bigodot_{i = l}^{u} f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A  &&  \text{if $l > u$}\\
        \bigodot_{i = l}^{u} f_i &= f_l \circ (\bigodot_{i = l + 1}^{u} f_i)  &&  \text{otherwise}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathop{\bigcirc}\limits_{i = l}^{u}` or else `\DeclareMathOperator*\bigcircop{\bigcirc}` and `\bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are `\mathop{\bigcirc}\limits_{i = l}^{u}` if you use it occasionally or if you plan to use it often, then `\DeclareMathOperator*\bigcircop{\bigcirc}` in the preamble and then `\bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}` for usage.  I show both usages below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*\bigcircop{\bigcirc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A  &&  \text{if $l > u$}\\
        \mathop{\bigcirc}\limits_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= f_l \circ 
          \Bigl(\bigcircop_{i = l + 1}^{u}\ f_i\Bigr)  &&  \text{otherwise}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, in `\textstyle` (inline) math, the super/sub-scripts on `\bigcircop` will revert to the normal super/sub style.

If you wanted to present the `\bigcirc` in a larger size, comparable to `\bigodot`, you could do this.  Here, I scale the `\bigcirc` to the same vertical footprint as the `\bigodot`, in a way that will preserve the current math style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*\bigcircop{\scalerel*{\bigcirc}{\bigodot}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= \mathrm{id}_A  &&  \text{if $l > u$}\\
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}\ f_i &= f_l \circ \Bigl(\bigcircop_{i = l + 1}^{u}\ f_i\Bigr)  &&  \text{otherwise}
    \end{align*}
\[
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}
        \textstyle\quad
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}
        \scriptstyle\quad
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}
        \scriptscriptstyle\quad
        \bigcircop_{i = l}^{u}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]