# summation symbol follows a circle

Tags: symbols

I wish to insert a circle in the front of the summation symbol as:

[image]

in the `equation` or `eqnarray` environment. How do I do that?

Comment: Please make clear to me: first should be the circle to which follows `\sum` symbol. Height of circle should be equal to height of symbol? Something like `$\bigcirc\sum$`? Written with new command?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your guide makes me find this address https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371217/placement-of-indices-using-bigcirc-in-math-mode   and by it I could reach the proposal.

Comment: ok, than you like to replace `\sum` with circle (as math operator). If so, than your question is duplicate to  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371217/placement-of-indices-using-bigcirc-in-math-mode and be closed as such.